# How do I run through an array where the first array member is a string that needs to be split

Tags: c#, string, foreach, split, for-loop

I have an array {{".txt|.doc|.docx", "100000"}, {".xls|.xlsx|.xxx" , "10000"}, ".npp", "100000"}

I am trying to find a way to run a foreach loop on each member of the array in a loop while also checking the first member as a string not an array.

The code will search for all docs greater than 10000 bytes, as long as the docs are txt, doc, docx, etc and then search all xls, and then npp.  Some of the members of the first part of the array have multiple types, some just one.  Is there an efficient way to do this?

I tried:
if (size == (size[2,i]) && ((ext != sextension[1, 0].ToUpper())) && ((ext != sextension[1, x].ToUpper())))

but obviously that doesn't work.
Sorry if this is not clear, but I am not sure how to explain it otherwise.

Comment: Show some more code - what programming language is it actually? Looks like PHP? Try using the code button for code (the 01101 button).

Comment: JavaScript?  Not clear the language.

Comment: c#
string[,] extension = new string[5,2]{ {".doc|.docx|.doc1","1000"} ,  {".xls", "1000"} , {".pdf","1000"}, {".zip", "10000"}, {".7z|.pz", "100000"} };
foreach (string p in array)
      {
        if (p == extension[0, 1]()) || ..ext2 = size or ..ext3 && (size) 
        {
         Console.WriteLine("Ext {0} has a file size equal to {1}", size_entention, size);

Comment: Basically I need to compare Files with a certain extension to a size, the problem is there are multiple extensions for the same file type, and if I try and 'split' the array (such as split '|' on doc, docx,. ...) I get back an array, and I can seem to do a:
If filewithext = 1000 || filewithext2 = 10000 || filewithex3 = 1000 when all of the extentions are in the same first part of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the code you put in the comment above:

```
c# string[,] extension = new string[5,2]{ 
  {".doc|.docx|.doc1","1000"} , 
  {".xls", "1000"} ,
  {".pdf","1000"},
  {".zip", "10000"}, 
  {".7z|.pz", "100000"} };

foreach (string p in array) 
{ 
  if (p == extension[0, 1]()) || ..ext2 = size or ..ext3 && (size) 
  {
     Console.WriteLine("Ext {0} has a file size equal to {1}", size_entention, size);
```

Does not make a whole lot of sense, but I will go for it (guessing all the way):

The best way to do the extension match given your data structure is to use `regEx.Match()`, however this can be slow.  (Remember if your search string is `.docx` you will need to make it `@"\.docx"` before calling `regEx.match()` -- `.` is reserved in regEx.

I don't suggest this, it is slow.  What you really want is a dictionary.  Here is an example of using dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, int> d = new Dictionary<string, int>();
d.Add(".doc", 1000);
d.Add(".docx", 1000);
d.Add(".doc1", 1000);
d.Add(".xls", 1000);
d.Add(".pdf", 1000);
d.Add(".zip", 10000);
d.Add(".7z", 100000);
d.Add(".pz", 100000);

foreach (string p in array) 
{ 
  if (d.ContainsKey(p)
    Console.WriteLine("Ext {0} has a file size equal to {1}",p, d[p]);
}
```

This will be much faster on the search that what you were doing.  Setting up the dictionary is slow so I would suggest caching it.

Comment: I apologize if I am not coming across clear.  The code I have isn't working, so that is why it doesn't make sense.  

I am trying to search a file system for all files with an extension, but for the same type of files (doc, docx, etc) I want to only compare once.  The problem I am running into is when I search for array[0,0] filetypes with size array[0,1] (in a loop) I want the if statement to compare array[0,0] (all of them after I split them).

So if file .docx || .doc || .rdoc == filesize then console.writeline.

Comment: use regex then, like I said -- it is a worse choice for whatever you are doing (which is still not clear).

Comment: note this : the example code above will do exactly what your example was trying to do -- try it in your code and see if it is actually what you want.

Comment: I ended up using a multimap class that I found, a dictionary one one key, multiple values.  But you pointed me in the right direction.  Thanks!